# Generate Hashcode for Valueranges

Tags: .net, dictionary, hashcode

Recently I encountered the following problem:
If a given value falls within a dedicated range of values, I want to display something special.
Since I did not know before starting my application how this ranges would look like or which values I need to check, I used a Dictionary to read the valueranges as keys and the outputs as values.
For the dictionary to work, I needed to override the equals and hash code functions, and here the problem starts.
How can I generate a hash code so that if my dictionary contains

```
//This is pseudo code
[0|10]->Low
[11|50]->Medium
[51-100]->High
```

and I query for 2, my Dictionary returns me `Low`

My way of resolving this was to simply override the getHashcode function of the Object buy always returning -1, so that in any case the equals method needs to be called. That doesn't sound like a good idea, but was the only solution that came to my mind.

Is there even any way to map the idea of hashcodes with value ranges, and if yes, how would that look like?

Code language of Answers does not matter, since I'm more interested in the general approach then in the language implementation

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `Dictionary` in the way that will be misleading to anyone that will try to understand your code in the future.
`Dictionary` is one of the most often used structures. Every programmer and application will expect from object that conforms to `IDictionary` interface to behave in certain way and to have one key connected to one value.

My suggestion is to use strategy pattern.

Create a class `AdditionalActionControler` with a list of possible display actions (list of strategy interfaces). You use it by executing:

`AdditionalActionControler.DoSomethingForGivenValue(value)`.

This method executes `TryDoSomethingForGivenValue` for every strategy object in the list. 
Method `TryDoSomethingForGivenValue` implementations:

LowStrategy -> if value from range 0 - 10 do something

MidStrategy -> if value from range 11 - 50 do something else
...

This approach:

- allows to dynamicly change elements on the strategy list.
- is easier to understand by others,
- is easier to test - you can test every strategy separately.
- is more open to future modifications.

For example, imagine that in the future you have to add another behavior for a new range that is overlaping others:

NewStrategy -> if value from range 5 - 20 do one more thing